# Neutral axis and 2nd moment of area

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, solid-mechanics

Does anyone know how I would find the horizontal neutral axis (*yc*) and 2nd moment of area of this cross section? (R = 210 mm) I know that [image] and that there needs to be the same amount of area on either side of the neutral axis, but I don't know how I'm supposed to put that into practice here.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi Welcome to Engineering. This looks like homework or exercise. Please update your post and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is most easily handled using the "table" form as shown below.

[image]

The result can be verified by selecting a more convenient reference line, to eliminate the potential mistake made in sign convention, as shown below.

Final checks:

- $y_{c(A)} = y_{c(B)}$
- Due to effect of substraction, the neutral axis must shifting above the centerline of the circle, so $y_c > R$.

[image]

Comment: Correction: Item 2 should be "rectangle", not square.